# UCT definition in 802.3bp protocol

Tags: raw-ethernet

when I read 802.3bp-2016 protocol, i met a term "UCT" which I can't find its definition. For example, in Fig 97-13 RFER monitor state diagram, there is a UCT flow from INIT_CNT to WAIT state. Can anybody help me to understand this definition?

Answer (score 1):

unconditional transition

IEEE 802.3 SECTION 1, 1.2.1 State diagram conventions

The label UCT designates an unconditional transition.